# Having issues compiling an exploit using GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was trying to compile a C exploit for a security class I'm in and was struggling to get GCC to perform. The issue is that my /usr/include folder is missing folders that GCC is looking for to handle the includes of the file. The first error below describes a folder that doesn't exist.

> asm/page.h: No such file or directory

What I've tried so far:

1. Symlink it with my /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/* folders, but files within that folder start throwing errors that they in turn can't find other files.
2. Using GCC's -I parameter to manually specify each folder to look in for my includes but this also doesn't work. (Below)

> gcc 10613.c -o workdamnit-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/asm-generic/  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/linux/ -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/asm-generic/ -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/linux/
>
> ERROR: In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33:0,
>                    from 10613.c:2:
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/linux/stddef.h:4:31: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

3. I updated the import statement to use page.h from my kali linux common headers. When I tried to run this, I received the below error:

   > 'PAGE_SIZE' undeclared (first use in this function).
4. Lastly, I tried to compile with wine gcc but this particular exploit uses a socket library that I guess can't be compiled on a windows machine.

GCC version: 5.3.1
Link to exploit: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10613/

My knowledge of C and its compilation requirements is very limited. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you wounder why **undefined behaviour** behaves - well - undefined. VTC because of "no problem at all"

Comment: Not really sure what you're saying. This isn't my C code. I think most exploitDB exploits are verified before they are let on to the site. If this is undefined it would imply the code is unfinished.

Comment: You should learn what "undefined behaviour" means. Don't try expert coding without knowing what that is!

Answer (score -2):

Please give a usable and compilable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Based on the errors, it looks like `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/linux/` should actually probably be `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include`.

Comment: when I try this I get several other errors:
4.4.0-kali1-common/include
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/asm-generic/signal.h:4,
                 from 10613.c:8:

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is more a comment, but as it addressed at the time what was the stated problem OP had, it was the best answer that could have been possible under the circumstances.